# Caching value to variable or calling function to return value, which is cheaper in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, iteration

Which is cheaper(ram and cpu wise)?

```
/* caching */
vector<T> vt;
// ... populate the vector
typedef vector<T>::size_type v_t_type ;

vt_type size = vt.size();
for(vt_type i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  // ... do stuff with the vector
```

OR

```
/* pulling */
for(vt_type i = 0; i < vt.size(); ++i)
  // ... do stuff with the vector
```

Don't know if caching and polling are the right terms, but the examples should be straight forward.

Is calling the .size() method on each iteration costly?

Let's assume that .size() does something simple like reading an int member variable from vt.

In PHP and Javascript caching is generally much cheaper than polling.

Comment: Implement both versions, benchmark with a realistic load. Even in PHP/JS, the difference is usually not important.

Comment: if .size() does something simple and then usually it would be declared as a static inline function which will get optimized out by the compiler anyways.  C++ is much much better at optimizations than PHP and Javascript; chances are you will end up creating a bulkier version if you are dealing with simple primitives; Benchmarking as millimoose suggested will give you empirical evidence;

Comment: Any compiler from pretty much the dawn of time will optimize this away.

Comment: Unless you want the value of `i`, it's more idiomatic to use the iterators (`std::for_each`), or `for (auto& value : vt)` in C++11.

Comment: If you find a compiler that *does not* optimize the second version to the first version, throw it away and try another one.

Comment: It is easier to develop and maintain not 'caching' the result of `.size()` thus until you have provide that calling `.size()` is a problem, or at least have very strong evidence that it could be, it is not a problem. Premature optimisation is a terrible crime.

Comment: @AhmedMasud, it's a non-static member function, it can't be `static`

Comment: @CodyGray It depends on what you do in the loop.  After all, the results of `vt.size()` could change due to code being executed in the loop.

Comment: grr.. silly me... `static` is extraneous to the point.  if it's an inline function it should be fine; sorry C fingers typed `static` without thought

Comment: @thecoshman Especially as the semantics are different; in order to cache the value, you have to ensure that the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: @TonyTheLion I know, real programmers daily crucify micro-optimization freaks. I's a coding style that I adopted for PHP and Javascript and when I see function calls inside iterations my hair goes white.

Comment: @Radu Even in PHP and JS this is dumb. In most use cases (i.e. not involving lots of polynomial-complexity number crunching) the performance penalty from not obsessively caching variables will get dwarfed by writing the result over the network / all the voodoo the renderer has to do to display your page. This *maybe* made sense when JS interpreters were really dumb and pages really really simple.

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can know which is faster is to actually
measure, and even then, that will only tell you for one
particular implementation on one particular platform, in one
particular context.  In general, write which ever feels cleanest
to you, and then, *if* you have a performance problem, and the
profiler says that it is do to something going on at this
location, try both and see.

FWIW: The issue is an optimization called loop invariant motion:
literally calling a function (not inlined) will be slower than
accessing a variable, at least on any architecture I can
imagine.  But compilers are pretty good at recognizing constant
expressions in a loop, and hoisting them out of the loop,
keeping the results in a register.  Whether it can do this for
the call to `vt.size()` depends at least partitially on what you
do in the loop.  In particular, if you pass `vt` by reference to
a function in another translation unit, and the compiler doesn't
do cross unit optimization, then the compiler cannot hoist the
function call, because the called function might change the
size.  Of course, if you do this, the difference in time between
the two versions won't be significant, so it doesn't matter.

### EDIT:

Just a note concerning `std::vector<>::size()`: in typical
implementations, it will be something along the lines of:

```
return endPtr - beginPtr;
```

, where `entPtr` and `beginPtr` are member variables of type
`T*`.  The function is almost always inline, and will be hoisted
out of the loop (at least when optimization is activated) *if*
the compiler can prove that `endPtr` and `beginPtr` cannot
change value in the loop.  If the loop is simple, it probably
can, and there will be no difference in the generated code for
the two versions.  If the loop is more complicated, it probably
cannot, but it doesn't matter, because the time to read the two
variables, and do the subtraction and the division is probably
negligible with regards to the rest of what you're doing in the
loop.

Answer (score 0):

STL is designed with speed in mind and hence size() would be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: Which doesn't really change anything.  Whether `size()` is inline or not doesn't impact whether it can be hoisted out of the loop or not.

Comment: More important fact would be that it can be cached automatically and thus be `O(1)`.